# What is the best way of replace CXF's JSONProvider (Jettison based) with MOXy?

Tags: json, cxf, eclipselink, moxy, jettison

I was wondering why MOXy is not providing a JSONProvider class similar to JACKSON to replace the default JSON provider in a jax-rs implementation?

This would be the easiest way to deal with all classes in a certain package.
What I ended up doing was to do the following as I feel that custom context resolver or MessageBodyWriter/Reader are mostly suited to handle certain classes, but not to handle all classes in a package especially if you have many classes.

Am I right?
What are your thoughts?
What is the best way to replace Jettison with MOXy in CXF to handle all classes in a package?

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;

public class MyJSONProvider<T> extends JSONProvider<T> {
    private static JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
    static {
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContextFactory.createContext("com.bp.bs", null);
        } catch (JAXBException jaxbe) {
            jaxbe.printStackTrace();
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(jaxbe);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(T obj, Class<?> cls, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] anns, MediaType m,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers, OutputStream os)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        Marshaller marshaller = null;
        try {
            marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE,
                    "application/json");
            marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
            marshaller.marshal(obj, os);
        } catch (JAXBException jaxbe) {
            jaxbe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) offers the `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider` class that can be used to enable it as the JSON-provider.

Below is an example of a JAX-RS Application class that configures `MOXyJsonProvider`.

```
package org.example;

import java.util.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider;

public class CustomerApplication  extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>(2);
        set.add(MOXyJsonProvider.class);
        set.add(CustomerService.class);
        return set;
    }

}
```

`MOXyJsonProvider` was added in EclipseLink 2.4.0.  The latest version is EclipseLink 2.4.1 which can be downloaded from the following link:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

Comment: Thank U SO MUCH as always, this was exactly what I was looking for! I ended up with the following spring config:`<bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider">
  <property name="attributePrefix" value="@"/>
  <property name="formattedOutput" value="true"/>
  <property name="includeRoot" value="true"/>
  <property name="marshalEmptyCollections" value="false"/>
  <property name="valueWrapper" value="$"/>
  <property name="namespaceSeparator" value=""/>
  <property name="namespacePrefixMapper" ref="jsonNamespaceMap" />
 </bean>`